# Prove that a given transformation is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Suppose $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is defined by $T(x, y, z) = (y −z, x−y, 2x+ 1)$, for $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ . Is $T$ a Linear Transformation? Justify your answer.

I started by multiplying $(y-z, x-y, 2x+1)$ by the identity matrix and ended up getting $(y-z, x-y, 2x)$. Does this mean it's not a linear transformation as it's not the same as the original?

Comment: Did you consider the possibility of using the definition of linear transformation?

Comment: Why do you think multiplying with the identity matrix delivers the answer you need? Do you know what you need to show?

Comment: Multiply any vector by the identity and you get the same vector. As said, just look at the definition of linearity and apply it. You might also look at some corollaries of linearity - if T is linear some other little things must be true.

Comment: T(1,0,0)+T(0,1,0)+T(0,0,1)=[0 1 -1, 1 -1 0, 2 0 0] this was using the first rule of linear transformations i thought

Answer (score 1):

$T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ being a linear transformation should satisfy properties of additivity and scalar multiplicity. i.e.,

1. $T(a+b) = T(a) + T(b)\ \ \forall \ \ a,b \in \mathbb{R}^3$
2. $T(\alpha * a) = \alpha T(a)\ \  \forall\ \ a \in \mathbb{R}^3, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

The second condition indirectly states that for $T$ to be a linear transformation, 
$T(0) = 0$. This is not the case with your given transformation.